# Django inclusion tag not showing data

Tags: python, html, django

I'n trying to create inclusion tag so I can display data in my navigation bar on every page. The tag will be included in the "base.html" so that way it should display everywhere.

**tags.py**

```
@register.inclusion_tag('menu.html')
def show_hoods(HoodList):
    gethoods = Hood.objects.all()
    return {'gethoods': gethoods}
```

**menu.html**

```
{% for hood in gethoods %}
<h3>{{ hood.name }}</h3>
{% endfor %}
```

For some reason the menu.html template is blank and is not showing any data.

Also, once I have the menu.html running, will simple {% include 'menu.html' %} work inside the base.html? Will that be automatically rendered?

**Edit:**
Based on the feedback below, the code above is correct, however the base.html code was incorrect as the inclusion_tag is not loaded with {% include %} but `{% load %}` is used instead.

**corrected base.html**

```
{% load tags %}
{% show_hoods hoodlist %}
```

Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: How are you adding your inclusion tag in base.html? Also, what is HoodList?

Comment: HoodList is just a name for the request, should I rename it to "request"? As per the base.html I was planning on using {% include %} tag.

Comment: You add inclusion tags using their names. So adding {% show_hoods %} in base.html should render menu.html with the list of Hood objects. Viewing menu.html directly  will show it empty as menu.html needs the context variables (gethoods) you pass into it in show_hoods.

Comment: Simply doing {% include menu.html %} in base.html would include the menu.html without passing it the gethoods context variable. Unless the gethoods context variable is made available by the view that renders base.html, this will also be empty. 

This is what inclusion tags are for - setting some extra context variables *and* rendering a template using these context variables.

Comment: Bob, thanks for the help. Everything is working now and I do appreciate your time and your help! I have updated my OP with the working code. Hopefully it will be helpful another Django rookie :)

Comment: No problem. Will write up an answer for this too then.

Comment: Alternatively, you can edit your question back to how it was to start with, and post your fix as an answer. That way it will be easier for someone with a similar problem to see what the fix is .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directly viewing the menu.html template will not display anything as it has no context variables set. `gethoods` will be empty so there will be nothing for the for loop in the template to loop over.

One of the main purposes of an include tag is to set extra context variables and then render a template using these variables. Directly viewing the template will show the template without the variables, but including the include template (`{$ show_hood %}` in your case) will add the context variables (`gethoods`) and render the template using them.

Answering your second question, you add include templates using their name, (the name of the function by default) rather than the `{% include %}` tag. The `{% include %}` tag is for when you simply want to render one template inside of another, and where it either doesn't need any context variables or uses the context variables available to its parent template.

Comment: Thanks for the detail info. Django is new to me as for the last 10+ years I have been working with apps where I was writing code, queries and including rendered templates directly into the templates. :)